# why is my if statement going to "else" even though it should stop at "else if"?

Tags: c, if-statement, while-loop

I'm trying to make a chomp game in c as a school assignment, but have been stuck at a silly IF - statement...
Basically, every time it runs (the CheckMove function), if I make a turn that isn't correct, it goes straight down to the else statement instead of returning the correct int... why??

I have removed lots of the code that isn't part of the problem. hope it is okay.. din't know if it is more appreciated to post the whole program instead...

Please help!

```
while(1)
    {
        PrintBoard();
        player = (player == 2) ? 1 : 2;

        while(1)
        {
            GetMove(player, move);

            if (CheckMove(move) == 0)  // if everything is fine, break the loop and change player
            { 
                UpdateBoard(move); 
                break;
            }
            else if (CheckMove(move) == 1) //this never gets triggered
            {
                printf("\nAlready taken. Please try again! (row col): ");
                continue;
            }
            else if (CheckMove(move) == 2) //this never gets triggered
            {
                printf("\nYou lost!\n");
                return 0;
            }
            else if (CheckMove(move) == 3) //This ALWAYS gets triggered
            {
                printf("\nIllegal move. Try again! (row col): ");
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}

void Initialize()... // initializes the board
void PrintBoard()... // prints the board

void GetMove(int player, int move[2])
{
    printf("\nPlayer %d: your move! (row col): ", player);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) scanf(" %d", &move[i]);
}
int CheckMove(int move[2])
{
    int check = 99;
    if ((move[0] >= 1  && move[0] < 5) && (move[1] >= 1  && move[1] <= 10))
    {
        move[0] -= 1;
        move[1] -= 1;
        // more checks
        if (board[move[0]][move[1]] == 'Z')
        {
            check = 1;
        }
        else if(board[move[0]][move[1]] == 'X')
        {
            check = 2;
        }
        else 
        {
            check = 0;
        }
    }
else { check = 3; } //as soon as I hit check 1 or 2, I end up here...
return check;    
}
```

Comment: every time you call `CheckMove` - it modifies `move` variable (`-=` part), it is better to introduce local vars like `int move0 = move[0] - 1; int move1 = move[1] - 1;`

Comment: ilyaBursov okay I'll do that. Why is it better tho?

Comment: it is better because you want to call function with the same argument multiple times, if first invocation modified input - subsequent calls are getting wrong data, maybe you also want to execute it ones and store in temp variable, then use the same variable in `if else` chain

Comment: Also, instead of calling `CheckMove(move)` many times, you may wish to call it only once and save the result; e.g. `int c = CheckMove(move);`, then do `if (c==0) {...} else if (c==1) {...} else if (c==2) {...}` etc.

Comment: @ilyaBursov thank you, I'll implement the changes and see where I land

Comment: @printf thank you, I'll implement the changes and see where I land